# Are MD5 digests consistent across different systems?

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5, portability, hashlib

Given this code:

```
import hashlib    

h = hashlib.md5()
h.update(str("foobar").encode('utf-8'))
```

Would the same digest be returned on any system?
If not, is there a way to ensure that it does?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, a correctly implemented MD5 algorithm will always produce the same digest for the same series of bytes on any system, since that is exactly what checksum algorithms like MD5 are for.

As a side note: `"foobar"` is already a string, so `str("foobar")` is doing nothing at all in your code above. A correct version of the code would be:

```
import hashlib    

h = hashlib.md5()
h.update("foobar".encode('utf-8'))
```

Also, note that MD5 is *not a secure cryptographic hash function*. It's fine to use it as a checksum to guard against accidental corruption, but it cannot be used to verify that data hasn't been intentionally altered.